# Stuck trying to use the value of a SQL COUNT(*) query as a value in another query in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, json, typescript

I've been trying to figure out how to store the total number of rows using a `COUNT(*)` query in a `const`. I would like to plug this `const` back into a different query's parameter which fetches the contents of the table rows. The `const` which stores the counted rows would be set to the `LIMIT ?`. I'm trying to use an `async` function with `await` but `Promises` are interfering with my queries type, thus returning an error. I'm aware that I can return all rows by simply not specifying a `LIMIT`, however I'm trying to implement pagination and knowing how to access simple things like `COUNT(*)` will go a long way. Below is my attempt (using MySQL 5.7.32):

```
export async function findByPerson(person: Person): Promise<Activity[]> {
 
 // Retrieve the total row count where person_id is specified by function parameter
  const query1 = 'SELECT count(*) AS count FROM person WHERE person_id = ?';
  const result1 = await db.query(query1, [person.id]);

  // Retrieve the contents of all rows where person_id = ? and LIMIT is specified in result2
  const query2 = `SELECT ${fields.join(',')} FROM person WHERE person_id = ? ORDER BY start_day DESC LIMIT ?`;

  // The number of rows I want to plug in as the LIMIT value should be the total row count from query1, which should be result1[0]
  const result2 = await db.query(query2, [person.id, result1[0]]);

  return Promise.all([result2[0].map(
    (row: ActivityRow) => recordToTable(person, row)
  )]);

}
```

The following error I receive is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''[object Object]'' at line 1"
```

To my understanding, `result1[0]` as the `LIMIT` when plugged into `query2` should return 190 rows for this particular person_id. I'm confused as to why `result1[0]` doesn't return an integer value representing the actual row count, it should output { count: '190' }, but I don't get this output. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result1[0].count` will give you 190, `result1[0]` will give you `{ count: '190' }`

```
export async function findByPerson(person: Person): Promise<Activity[]> {
 
 // Retrieve the total row count where person_id is specified by function parameter
  const query1 = 'SELECT count(*) AS count FROM person WHERE person_id = ?';
  const result1 = await db.query(query1, [person.id]);

  // Retrieve the contents of all rows where person_id = ? and LIMIT is specified in result2
  const query2 = `SELECT ${fields.join(',')} FROM person WHERE person_id = ? ORDER BY start_day DESC LIMIT ?`;

  // The number of rows I want to plug in as the LIMIT value should be the total row count from query1, which should be result1[0]
  const result2 = await db.query(query2, [person.id, result1[0].count]);

  return Promise.all([result2[0].map(
    (row: ActivityRow) => recordToTable(person, row)
  )]);

}
```